# Explaination for size difference betwen Webpack / Vuejs import vs Vue.component()

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

I have been doing some refactoring of my single file components in a Vue.js project.  Originally I was using the `Vue.component()` method in my main app.js file to require numerous single file components which were only used once as children of other parent components.  So instead of requiring them in the app.js I decided to import them in the respective parent components to keep things a little more succinct and organized.

Then I noticed one method over the other creates a larger compiled file. Note the 'Size' in the example below.

Example from my compiled SettingsMenu:

```
// Size 100,455 bytes
Vue.component('SettingsMenu' require(./components/SettingsMenu.vue));

// Size 100,778  bytes
import SettingsMenu from '../SettingsMenu.vue';

// Size 100,747 bytes
// leaving both require / import
```

The last result stuck me as very strange that leaving the import in place and also requiring the component in the main app.js reduced the size a small amount.

I would prefer to use the import method to keep all the related or dependent components together but since it produces a slightly larger final file it makes it less than desirable.

**Is there some reason importing a component in this way makes a larger file size and most importantly is there some way I can mitigate or eliminate the difference?**

Answer (score 0):

> but since it produces a slightly larger final file it makes it less than desirable.

31 bytes difference. Are you serious, lol?

Comment: That is for one child component.  One of many, so yes I am serious.  They add up over time.  And how is that an answer?

Comment: You happen to have 20.000 components?

Comment: The difference is 334 bytes not 31 between using the `Vue.component()` method and import.  I don't understand the antagonism?

Comment: Still insignificant.